# Cookie doesn't get deleted

Tags: php, cookies

:D

I have a problem with a login and registration script. It has "remember me" functionality and it works great unless i log out. It stores that cookie in a database(just to check on it later) and when i log out it gets deleted from that db(which is the way it's supposed to work) the problem however is that it doesn't get deleted from the browser(even tho it doesn't get deleted from the browser when i come back i'll be logged out because of the check it's makeing on that, previously mentioned, db).

Here is my user class(you can see there a logout method(line 85)

```
<?php

class User{
    private $_db,
        $_data,
        $_sessionName,
        $_cookieName,
        $_isLoggedIn;

    public function __construct($user = null){
        $this->_db = DB::getInstance();

        $this->_sessionName = Config::get('session/session_name');
        $this->_cookieName = Config::get('remember/cookie_name');

        if(!$user){
            if(Session::exists($this->_sessionName)){
                $user = Session::get($this->_sessionName);

                if($this->find($user)){
                    $this->_isLoggedIn = true;
                } else{
                    //process logout
                }
            }
        } else{
            $this->find($user);
        }
    }

    public function create($fields = array()){
        if(!$this->_db->insert('users', $fields)){
            throw new Exception('There was a problem creating an account');
        }
    }

    public function find($user = null){
        if($user){
            $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';
            $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));

            if($data->count()){
                $this->_data = $data->first();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function login($username = null, $password = null, $remember = false){
        if(!$username && !$password && $this->exists()){
            Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
        } else{
            $user = $this->find($username);
            if($user){
                if($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)){
                    Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);

                    if($remember){
                        $hash = Hash::unique();
                        $hashCheck = $this->_db->get('users_session', array('user_id', '=', $this->data()->id));

                        if(!$hashCheck->count()){
                            $this->_db->insert('users_session',array(
                                'user_id' => $this->data()->id,
                                'hash' => $hash
                            ));
                        } else{
                            $hash = $hashCheck->first()->hash;
                        }
                    Cookie::put($this->_cookieName, $hash, Config::get('remember/cookie_expiry'));
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function exists(){
        return(!empty($this->_data)) ? true : false;
    }

    public function logout(){
        $this->_db->delete('users_session', array('user_id', '=', $this->data()->id));

        Session::delete($this->_sessionName);
        Cookie::delete(Config::get('remember/cookie_name'));
    }

    public function data(){
        return $this->_data;
    }

    public function isLoggedIn(){
        return $this->_isLoggedIn;
        }
}
```

And here is my Cookie class(you can see a delete cookie method on line 19)

```
<?php

class Cookie{
    public static function exists($name){
        return(isset($_COOKIE[$name])) ? true : false;
    }

    public static function get($name){
        return $_COOKIE[$name];
    }

    public static function put($name, $value, $expiry){
        if(setcookie($name, $value, time() + $expiry, '/')){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static function delete($name){
        self::put($name, '', time() - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that you always set cookie expire by time() + X, even when you "delete" it, either you you change the delete method to something like this: setcookie ($name, "", time() - 3600); or you modify your put function (which might be more work since you'll need to update all function calls).

Comment: now i'm using this
`
public static function delete($name){
  setcookie($name, '', time() - 3600);
 }
`
it still doesn't delete it from the browser :(

Comment: @emma you're setting the cookie to a path '/'.
for removing cookie try using `setcookie($name, '', time() - 3600, '/');` I believe it will work

Comment: o my god, devsourav, it worked <3 thank you soooo much <3<3<3<3<3

Answer (score 0):

I think you are sending an wrong as timestamp to setcookie :

self::put($name, '', time() - 1);

you should call like this:

self::put($name, '', - 1);

Because if use "time() -1 " will result a timestamp in the future : time() + time() -1